# Nuxt-link change the url but not the page content

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Whenever I am using this in **components/feed.vue** :

```
<template><div><nuxt-link :to="{path: '/videos/new', query: { page:nextpage(currentpage) } }">next</nuxt-link></div></template>
```

or

```
<template><div><nuxt-link :to="'/videos/new/?page=' + nextpage(currentpage)">next</nuxt-link></div></template>
```

When I click on the link the url changes but the content stay the same, did I miss something ?

edit : its working when I am on "/" but it doesnt if I am already on "/videos/new"

Comment: What's your `pages` folder structure?

Comment: The links are in components/feed.vue and the page I want to change is /pages/_slug.vue (this page also include my feed.vue component).

Comment: @sthotakura its working when I am on "/" but it doesnt if I am already on "/videos/new" and I want to go to "/videos/new?page=2"

Comment: Does your component process `page` param?

Comment: What do you mean ? Sorry I am new to Nuxt and Vue

Comment: @sthotakura do I need to use watchQuery ?

Comment: In Nuxt, the route is generated according your `/pages` structure. I suggest you read official Routing Doc "Dynamic Routes" section https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/

Comment: @SCKim my routes are working...

Comment: can i see your `/videos/new` code? and also can you tell me when you click in link what is the url exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Finally it was very simple, just need to add watchQuery :

```
export default {
 watchQuery: ['page', 'order', 'q']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to see `[YOUR-PROJECT]/.nuxt/router.js` file of your project which is auto-generated routing. In this file you can find your auto-generated route urls and names. And in nuxt-link, please use route name instead path.

Further information -> https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#basic-routes

Comment: That doesnt change the fact that when I go from /new to /new?page2 the page dont reload,  only the URL changes.

Comment: show me some part of your source code. Or demo link.

Comment: It wa s just a watchQuery thing